# How to make Multiple dependent dropdown in CRUD Django?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, visual-studio-2010, jquery-select2-4

Fields are such as;
Phone Name(Field1)
Samsung
Redmi

Phone Model(Field2)
M30
Note10

Note : Dependency between Phone Name and Phone Model(if select samsung from the dropdown then M30 should comes and if select Redmi from the dropdown then Note10 should come.

State(Field3)
Karnataka
Andhra

City(Field4)
Bangalore
Tirupathi

Note : Dependency between State and City(if i select "Karnataka" from the dropdown then "Bangalore" should come and if i select "Andhra" from the dropdown then "Tirupathi" should come.

Data & Time(Field5)
Company Name(Field6)

### I need form design Horizontally(col-6) in Separate page

Phone Name(Field1)          Phone Model(Field2)
State(Field3)               City(Field4)
Data & Time(Field5)         Company Name(Field6)

### I need Retrieving Data from database in Separate page

Example:                                                                                                          Phone name Phone Model State City Company Name                                                                ---------- ----------- ----- ---- -------------

Comment: you have to use Ajax to do it. here's the reference [Tutotial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: I have already watched it. Please create one mini CRUD project including my criteria if you can.

Comment: its not that hard. Follow Youtube Tutorials you will get it.

Comment: in that only one dependent dropdown is there but i want to two dependent dropdown, Example: Between Phone name and Phone Model | State and City

Comment: you can do any number of the dependent dropdown. in simple words, on the first drop-down click it will make a function call and return data based on your chosen option. this process can be repeated as long as you want.